# How to draw a UIBezierPath with an ARC to the right similar to the image shown?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

How do I draw this UIBezierPath to make it look identical to the green strip on the left of the image below? The rounded arc to the right.

[image]

```
path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 80))

//Add Half Circle Arc To Right
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 160), radius: bounds.width, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 90, clockwise: true)

path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 215))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: bounds.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.maxY))

path.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a routine that given the height of the desired arc and how far this “bubble” should stick out, and will determine the desired arc angle, radius, and center offset.

To determine the center of the circle giving three points on that circle is to identify the chord between two points and then identify the line that bisects that line segment. That results in a line that goes through the center of the circle. Then repeat that for a different two points on the circle. The intersection of those two lines will be the center of the circle.

[image]

So, I used a little basic algebra to calculate the slope (`m`), the y-intercept (`b`), and the x-intercept (`xIntercept`) of the line that bisects the line segment between the start of the arc and its half point. We can take that line, and see where it intercepts the x-axis and determine the center of the circle.

From that, a little trigonometry gives us the angle and the radius of the arc that intersects these three points (the top of the arc, the middle of the arc, and the bottom of the arc).

You get something like:

```
/// Calculate parameters necessary for arc.
/// - Parameter height: The height of top half of the arc.
/// - Parameter distance: How far out the arc should project.

func angleRadiusAndOffset(height: CGFloat, distance: CGFloat) -> (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) {
    let m = distance / height
    let b = height / 2 - distance * distance / (2 * height)
    let xIntercept = -b / m
    let angle = atan2(height, -xIntercept)
    let radius = height / sin(angle)
    return (angle, radius, xIntercept)
}
```

And you can then use that to create your path:

```
var point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY)
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: point)
point.x += edgeWidth
path.addLine(to: point)
point.y += bubbleStartY
path.addLine(to: point)
let (angle, radius, offset) = angleRadiusAndOffset(height: bubbleHeight / 2, distance: bubbleWidth)
let center = CGPoint(x: point.x + offset, y:point.y + bubbleHeight / 2)
path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -angle, endAngle: angle, clockwise: true)
point.y = bounds.maxY
path.addLine(to: point)
point.x = bounds.minX
path.addLine(to: point)
path.close()
```

And that yields:

[image]

That’s using these values:

```
var edgeWidth: CGFloat = 10
var bubbleWidth: CGFloat = 30
var bubbleHeight: CGFloat = 100
var bubbleStartY: CGFloat = 80
```

But you can obviously adjust these values as needed.